# How to revert to the Debug window after getting Usage in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am debugging and I want to find usage of some class/var/method.  I click on it and choose `Find Usage` but that opens a usage window over the debug one.  After that, I do not know how to get rid of it (or push it to the background) and see the debug window again.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Mac try: `command+5` or from the menu: `view->tool windows->debug`